# Store Ratings in Quod Libet

Tags: music-player, id3, quodlibet

I use [Quod Libet](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) as music library player. If I rate a song, the rating is successfully stored, but it seems at first only locally.

Only if I edit some tags and save them, I get the rating stored in the ID3 Tag in the field `POPM`:

```
$ mid3v2 test.mp3 |grep -a POPM

POPM=quodlibet@lists.sacredchao.net=0 153/255
```

I already tried activating the Plugin "ForceWrite" but that didn't change anything.

I use version Quod Libet 3.2.-1

Is there a way to store all ratings directly in the ID3-Tag?

Answer (score 1):

actually, activating the 'Force Write' plugin is not enough.

We need to right click on the song and click "plugins -> Force Write". You can also do this per album.

:)